# What is the best way to structure and name files which contain generic classes with the same name?

Tags: c#, .net

In my current project I have come across the requirement to create generic classes with the same name, but different numbers of generic parameters.  For example:

```
MyClass<T1>
MyClass<T1, T2>
MyClass<T1, T2, T3>
```

Given that I want all of these in the same namespace, I am confused as to how to structure and name my classes and files?

If we follow the idea that we should have classes limited to one per file and that files should be in a folder structure that represents namespace hierarchy and that the name of the file should match the name of the class, how do I deal with this situation?

What I am really asking here is what should I name the **file** that contains `MyClass<T1>`, and what should I name the **file** that contains `MyClass<T1, T2>`?  I am not asking what the names of the type parameters should be.

Comment: Give us some *specific* examples that describe the problem in better detail. The examples you've provided are too... erm, *generic.*  What do you mean by "how to structure and name my classes and files?"

Comment: Microsoft does this itself by just appending a number to the type parameter.  See the Tuple docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Pete: That really only applies to Tuple.  Microsoft also uses the `TKey, TValue` convention.  Func has a `TResult` type parameter.  Though I do agree that you can use `T1`, `T2`, etc. for a variable number of input parameters that don't otherwise have specific uses like `TKey` and `TValue`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well, yes but only in the context of an actual key/value collection such as a dictionary.  For anything consisting of a variable number of types they append a number.  Here's another example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd402872(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `Action` only looks that way because there's no output parameter, unlike `Func`.

Comment: I have edited my question to further clarify what I was asking.

Comment: Well, your edits obsolete some of the comments. :)  Why can't you just keep the classes in the same physical file?  If they're so different that you need to keep them in separate files then can you tell us what makes them different?

Comment: Stylecop rightly complains if you have more than one public class in a file.  Generally it's considered bad practice to place multiple classes in a single file as it makes things harder to find and deal with.

Comment: What does Stylecop say about naming the files?  Nothing?  I didn't think so.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
MyGenericClass`1.cs
MyGenericClass`2.cs
MyGenericClass`3.cs
```

And so on, where the number after the backtick is the number of generic type parameters.  This convention is used by Microsoft.

Alternatively, you can use something like

```
MyGenericCollectionClass[TKey, TValue].cs
```

which preserves not only the number of generic type parameters, but also their specific names.  Granted, it doesn't preserve the angle brackets, but we can't have everything in life we want, can we?

Comment: The compiler internally mangles the name of generic types, adding a backtick and the number of generic parameters since .NET does not allow multiple types with the same name with a differing number of generic parameters but C# does. So the file naming convention matches what the compiler does.

Comment: I wanted to prove you wrong, but actually you are correct:

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.Collections.Immutable/src/System/Collections/Immutable  I don't like this convention.

Comment: @Den, it seems that now they have regreted from that convention. Maybe it implied some problem? https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/commit/eef844ecd30ff2aff2f82d4b73baee356e7b0d08

Comment: @Sam Hopefully, not a communication problem between Microsoft teams. Because nobody else is doing it. Also it's up for the compiler team, not library team to decide in my opinion.

Comment: I'd not have the balls for using  " ` " in a file name.

Comment: @CristianE. Why?   It's a legal character.

Answer (score 4):

In the case of `Tuple` and `Action` that Pete has mentioned, Microsoft themselves use a single file - see [Tuple.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/tuple.cs) and [Action.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/action.cs).

I think it partly depends on whether or not the functionality for all the classes is basically the same. Personally I dislike lumping classes into a single file, but this might be an exception. In the source code where I work I added an autogenerated (using T4) `NamedTuple` class which acts in the same way as `Tuple`, but with a string name as the first argument into the constructor.

To answer your question, if you don't want to use a single file, perhaps use MyClass_1.cs for `MyClass<T1>`, MyClass_2.cs for `MyClass<T1, T2>`, etc.

Neither option is ideal though, so I'd be inclined to suggest the "Microsoft do it this way, so..." argument.

Comment: `Tuple` and `Action` are all delegates; they don't have any implementation code, so putting all of the variations in separate files would be kinda pointless anyway.  Just proves that every rule has an exception.

Comment: Yeah generally speaking putting multiple public delegates into the same file is considered ok (provided they're related).

Comment: @RobertHarvey, `Tuple` is not a delegate, but each implementation is short anyway.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez: Right, I was thinking of `Func`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you asked yourself, if the classes do really have the same intent? If one class is more generic than the other, then it will be a **GenericClass**, a **MoreGenericClass** and a **MostGenericClass**. Imagine that each type parameter of a class adds a new dimension to the class, so it may help to ask what dimension it is.

Lets take this example:

- `Container<Thing>`
- `MetricContainer<Thing, Metric>`
- `MetricTransportableContainer<Thing, Metric, Transport>`

I'm aware, that it is not the best example, but very expressive to show three dimensions:

- inner Dimension, what it can load
- metric Dimension, with which metric it can be loaded, only by count of things or by square measure or by cubical capacity or by weight
- outer Dimension, where it can be loaded.

So you can model transportation of cars:

```
Container<Cars>
MetricContainer<Cars, CountMetric>
MetricTransportableContainer<Cars, CountMetric, Ship>
```

Transportation of fluids:

```
Container<Fluid>
MetricContainer<Fluid, Volume>
MetricTransportableContainer<Fluid, Volume, Shelf>
```

Transportation of energy:

```
Container<Energy>
MetricContainer<Energy, ElectricPower>
MetricTransportableContainer<Energy, ElectricPower, Box>
```

Transportation of sugar, cereals:

```
Container<CrumblyMaterial>
MetricContainer<CrumblyMaterial, Weight>
MetricTransportableContainer<CrumblyMaterial, Weight, Silo>
```

Oh, what a surprise: a `List<T>` has one dimension that represents the things the list can hold; and this is a `Map<T, S>` with two dimensions that represent the things the map can hold and the access keys.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question.  Look at the last paragraph of the question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Please read the question carefully: classname should be aquivalent to filename. It's interchangeably. The problem lies in wrong analysis of the class and wrong naming of the generic classes in general. To sum up my answer: "Name it what it is and not what it seems to be."

Comment: [You can't put angle brackets in a file name.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @RobertHarvey You are kiding me ;-) Put Container<Thing> into file Container.cs. Put MetricContainer<Thing, Metric> into file MetricContainer.cs and put MetricTransportableContainer<Thing, Metric, Transport> into MetricTransportableContainer.cs. Please read my last sentence carefully than you will understand that the question handles three completely different objects.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Read my answer: Put one class into one file!

Comment: That doesn't address generic parameters that have no shape, like `Tuple<T1, T2, T3>`,  Unless your proposal is to name it `ContainerWithThreeGenericParameters.cs`.  It is you that is failing to read, not me.

Comment: @RobertHarvey To avoid such failing names I instantly recommended analysing the intend of the class to finally name the classes what the are and not how many generic parameters they have. That's why I cited the very simple classes List and Map.

Comment: There is no intent in generic parameters like T1, T2 and T3.  Those generic parameters are deliberately intended to assume *anything.*  How would you propose to deal with something like `Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8>`?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I wrote intent of the classes not intent of the generic parameters.

Comment: I think you're missing the point.  The question asks: How do I put `Tuple<T1>`, `Tuple<T1, T2>` and `Tuple<T1, T2, T3>` into separate CS files in a standard way, without name clashes?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Name it Singleton, Pair, Triple, Quadruple, Quintuple and so on. And if you really generate the classes automatically, I would name it TupleWith1Dimension, TupleWith2Dimensions, TupleWith3Dimensions and so on. That all are short descriptive names for clean code.

Comment: @shylynx: If the classes are generated automatically, and should always be replaced as a unit, what advantage is there to separating each class to a different file?  I would think that would simply increase the danger that someone might e.g. end up with one version of Tuple1, Tuple2, and Tuple4 but a different version of Tuple3 (e.g. because an earlier version of the project didn't need Tuple3, but a later one did, and it got fetched from a different place).